# Design common decision file to different targets in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, abstract-factory

I've to manage a number of targets from my single code base. For each target I've to set some properties like theme color, header name etc. I'm able to acheive this using protocol and Common class implementing protocol which returns values as according targets. But that requires to create object of target class type. I don't want to create create object. I just want to extend protocol which returns values which have been set statically for each target class.

Below is my code:

```
protocol AbstractProtocol {
    func getServerUrl() -> String
}
```

Common class extending protocol which return default value

```
class AbstractClientFactory: AbstractProtocol
{
    func getServerUrl() -> String
    {
        return "Default URL"
    }
}
```

Target class extending Generic implementation and return value as according

```
class InspectClient1: AbstractClientFactory {
    override func getServerUrl() -> String {
        return "Target1 url value"
    }
}
```

Target 2 Class

```
class InspectClient2: AbstractClientFactory {
    override func getServerUrl() -> String {
        return "Target 2 url"
    }
}
```

Added a bridge class which return client type at compile time

```
class AbstractClient
{
    class func createAbstractClient() -> AbstractProtocol
    {
        return InspectClient1() 
    }
}
```

In ViewController, i'm getting target url

```
AbstractClient.createAbstractClient().getServerUrl()
```

I want to achieve this without returning object of target type. Is these any other possible way to call override method by extending protocol in view controller?
i.e 
VC -> protocol -> first calls getUrl of default Implementation -> then call InspectClient1/InspectClient2 override getURl method as per target

Is it possible, without returning object?

Comment: Use a global variable instead and of an a wapper class.  Your config could also be a enun.

Comment: @Sulthan - if i add global variable or enum then i've to use them with if -else right? which i don't want.Could you please suggest another solution?

Comment: Nope, that is not what I meant.

Comment: @Sulthan - Could you please post example code here?

Comment: I hope I understand your question correctly. Is it about switching app configurations?

Comment: @Sulthan - i've gone through this apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH8-SW1.is there any way to  implement Class factory method  in swift to acheive target decision condition?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need protocols for that. Different targets can have different classes with the same names.
For example, you can create a class or a file named "Constants" or something like that.

```
class Constants { //target 1
    let url = "target 1 url"
}

class Constants { //target 2
    let url = "target 2 url"
}
```

And then call the `url` property from any class in the target.

You can also create a protocol with extensions (each extension for a target) with same names.

The only disadvantage is that you need to add all the constants to all your targets, otherwise they won't build. On the other hand, you can see what you're missing at compile time and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to achieve what you want but there is one decision you need to make - do you want to switch configurations at runtime? E.g. for debugging?

If you want to switch configurations at runtime, you can simply use an enum:

```
 enum MyTarget {
    case test
    case production

    var url: String {
        switch self {
        case .test:
           return "my test url"
        case .production:
           return "my production url"
    }
}
```

and a global variable holding the current target:

```
var currentTarget: MyTarget = .test
```

Changing that value of this variable will change your settings everywhere (probably you should also trigger a notification to update UI etc.).

Your url can be accessed simply by `currentTarget.url`.

If you don't want to switch configurations at runtime, you can wrap your configuration parameters into a struct or class:

```
#if MY_CONFIG_TEST
class Config {
    static let url = "my test url"
}
#elif MY_CONFIG_PRODUCTION
class Config {
    static let url = "my test url"
}
#endif
```

Accessing your url simply by `Config.url`.

No need for protocols or abstract classes, no need for singletons.